# Handle Ajax redirect and load content into new page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using Ajax to dynamically update a data table without refreshing. I have no problem so far. The user selects certain criteria from a Form . The issue is that , I no longer want to fetch content to this same page but I want to redirect and load content on a different template:

Users selection (**Page1.html**) -> Ajax -> redirect to **Page2.html** -> load data within Page2

Would someone please have a look at the code below and advise why it is not working ? I am able to redirect but there isn't any returned data.

**Ajax**

```
if (t && e ) {
    dataArray = new Array;
    dataArray[0] = e;
    dataArray[1] = t;

 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "includes/filter.php",
   data: {
       Name: e,
       Color: t,
          },

        success: function (e) {           

        window.location.href = 'Page2.html';  // Redirect to this page
        $("#Wrapper").html(e);    // Load content to this page in Div # Wrapper

        // If I Uncomment the two lines above and just add $("#table").html(e); it will successfully load content within the table div on the same page

        }
    });
  }
```

Where filter.php handles the server side query and outputs an html table with the data.
THanks

Comment: Umm..once it reaches `window.location.href`, it would have redirected to that page and there is no data being passed along with it. Why not on redirect, use query to fetch the data on that page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass e and t to your next page like

```
window.location.href = 'Page2.html?e=' + e + '&t=' + t;
```

Once page2 is loaded, get e and t and make your ajax call and replace html of wrapper. In your current solution page2 is loaded before wrapper html gets replaced.

for creating query string from array:

```
var array = [],
array["Name"] = "Car";
array["Color"] = "Red";
var queryStr = "";

for (var key in array){
  if(queryStr != "") queryStr += "&";
  queryStr += key + "=" + array[key];
}

var url = "Page2.html?" + queryStr;
```

Comment: Thanks it seems Im getting somewhere, just a quick one, saying having an array with values of e + t + n + r, insteade of passing 'Page2.html?e=' + e + '&t=' + t + '&n=' + n + '&r=' + r; How would I loop through an array dataArray and post the keys which are set ? As user may select 2 out of 4 ect.. and posting the 4 as above will output in the URL, page2.html?Name=car&color=red,, ( empty colons)

Comment: Creating a query string from array shouldn't be an issue. I am not sure how your array is structured but you can loop it and start appending key values to your URL string

Comment: I know it's a different topic, but if you could point me to any tutorial on how to loop through the array and append key/values that exist to the url ? I would appreciate it. Thanks again

Comment: I have updated my solution to include code for creating query string from array.

Answer (score 1):

> Try this:

```
if (t && e ) {
        dataArray = new Array;
        dataArray[0] = e;
        dataArray[1] = t;

     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "includes/filter.php",
       data: {
           Name: e,
           Color: t,
              },

            success: function (data) {           

            window.location.href = 'Page2.html?data='+data ;  // Redirect to this page


            }
        });
      }
```

> After send to the request to the page using POST. And add this line in
>   page2.html  $("#Wrapper").html(e);

Comment: it just returns the results in the address bar, doesn't load content in page2, as Jd mentioned below. Thanks

Comment: then get the results using post method if(isset($_POST['data'])) { $data = $_POST['data'];  $("#Wrapper").html($data); }

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to clearly choose your path :

- Option 1 : drop the ajax request, and do open a new window

  `window.open('Page2.html?filter=yabayabayaba')`
- Option 2 : use an ajax request, and load the result in a dialog box (using bootstrap or jquery-ui)

  `success: function (e) {    $(e).dialog();    }`

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong here.

1. When `window.location.href = 'Page2.html';` executes it stops the rest of the code from executing and redirects the browser.
2. The `$("#Wrapper").html(e);` is in your AJAX success function. So it
   will only ever fire after the AJAX call. When the new page loads
   this code isn't executed. (It will never fire anyway because of the redirect in front of it).

The whole point of AJAX is to not redirect the user. If you're redirecting them anyway then why not just have the correct content in Page2.html when it loads rather than inserting it with javascript?

Alternatively, you could drop the redirect and just load the entire Page2.html file into your current page in place of the original template using an AJAX request.

I don't know what your HTML looks like but if Page2.html has a div named #wrapper all you need to do is load everything from inside #wrapper of Page2.html into the #wrapper of Page1.html like this:

```
$('#wrapper').load('Page2.html #wrapper');
```

That code you should go in your AJAX success function in place of the redirect. You can see more about .load() [here](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Comment: I can't have a static content on page2, it is just a styled page I would like to use to display tabular data, I would like to try the second method, loading the entire page2.html, would you please advise how can it be done ? $(body).load('page2.html')-> return (e) within page2 in #Wrapper ?

Comment: Yeah, that is more or less how you could do it. See my updated answer :)